# regex to find leading hashes not followed by a space

Tags: regex

I want to fix markdown headers that are missing a space after the hash

### valid markdown vs invalid markdown headers

```
this one is valid:

### CAUSE:  

this one isn't:

###CAUSE:
```

I can find valid ones just fine (and ignore invalid ones) with:

`^#+\s+` or `^#+[\s]+`

The problem when I want negate the space following the hash, i.e. flag all the ones **not** followed by a space which are invalid markdown.

I've tried @ https://regex101.com/, using the Python flavor.

`^#+[^\s]+`

However, it IS matching partially, up to the hashes:

```
### CAUSE:
 matches the 3 hashes
```

Same problem with `^#+[^ ]+`

How do I reject `### CAUSE`, entirely but match `###CAUSE`?

(note:  a simple state machine checks whether I am in a code block, so a `#comment` in a bash or Python code block isn't a problem).

Also, while regex 101 is doing this, I only used it because this is the behavior I am getting from Python 3.8 itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure the first non-whitespace char is not `#`:

```
^#+[^\s#]\S*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQ1SN0/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (or line, if `re.M` option is used)
- `#+` - 1 or more `#` chars
- `[^\s#]` - any char but whitespace and `#`
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars.

Actually, you may also achieve it with other regular expressions. Say, you may use a negative lookahead based pattern:

```
^(?!#+\s)#+\S+
```

Here, `(?!#+\s)` would fail the match if there is a whitespace after one or more `#` chars.

Comment: ok, that does seem to work. And I accept it is above my regex paygrade. but what is actually originally wrong with my form?  Same as yours, up to item 3.  I ask for 1 or more non-whitespace `[^\s]+` so why does `### C` match up to `###`?

Comment: oh, I think I get it.  the last '#` in `###` is causing the match.

Comment: @JLPeyret See [this debugger](https://regex101.com/r/8oud9O/1/debugger), `^#+` grabs the three `#`s at the start, then `\S+` (=`[^\s]+`) makes the regex engine backtrack and the third `#` is matched with this `\S+`, and the match is found.